# Getting captcha if i am executing my scripts in Jenkins server

Tags: selenium, jenkins, cookies, robotframework

I am getting captcha in login page. Am executing my scripts using Jenkins server and my Jenkins server is hosted in Linux machine.
If i am executing in Windows i am not getting any captcha. i am using below chrome options for Chrome.
Is there any possibility to handle this issue using Cookies. Can someone please suggest me.

Note : I am using robot framework for Testing.

```
${options}  Evaluate  sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()  sys, selenium.webdriver
Call Method  ${options}  add_argument  --start-maximized
Call Method  ${options}  add_argument  --headless
Call Method  ${options}  add_argument  --disable-gpu
Call Method  ${options}  add_argument  args: ['--disable-setuid-sandbox', '--no-sandbox']
```